# How to search a field inside a child database of a child database? Parent > Child > Child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have my database structure like this:

**Delivery:**

- id
- user_id

**User:**

- id
- company_id

**Company:**

- id
- name

Now I'm building a search query for deliveries:

```
elsif params[:option] == "company_name"

    @deliveries = Delivery.joins(company: :user)
    .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    .where("company.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    .order("created_at DESC")
```

Now, this is not working. What I'm trying to do is to filter the deliveries according to the company name. How can I do this? Search a field inside a child of a child?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error?

Comment: @THpubs replace this line `.where("company.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")` with this ``.where("companies.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")`` because you need to take table name instead of model name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to provide table name as `companies` and join `company` through `user`.

```
elsif params[:option] == "company_name"

    @deliveries =
      Delivery.joins(user: :company)
        .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
        .where("companies.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
        .order("created_at DESC")
```